# Effects of the sun on Einstein's prediction of gravitational bending of light

Tags: general-relativity, optics, visible-light

From what I understood, $1.75''$ was the predicted value derived by Einstein.

Is it possible that light from the star, at the time of solar eclipse, can also be bent somehow by the solar particles near the sun?

Is it possible that the electromagnetic field from the sun influenced the light ray from the star, since light is an electromagnetic wave?

Is it possible that the ejected charged particles near the sun created an atmosphere that interfered and contributed in bending the light?

And also if one could provide a reference where these are dealt with, please drop me a link.

Any suggestions or clarification is welcomed.

I just wanted to know if the above conditions would be possible and their contribution was accounted for in considering the measurement was indeed a gravitational influence in this particular experiment. Thank you.

Comment: My understanding is that two electromagnetic waves cannot interact if it is not coherent enough (i.e. like a laser). You may want to look it up in optics or laser physics sources. In practice, there is no measurable effect of interaction between light particles from the sun and travelling light that is bent by the gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is thought to be discounted, it's too small an effect. Light refraction by electrons in plasmas is well understood, and is known to be mostly non-dispersive, and the density of free electrons not vary too much near the measurable deflection to cause any speed of light differences for refraction. it would be too small to have had any effect in the observed 1.75 arc seconds bending of light by GR.

See the discussion in the question at Researchgate.net at https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_sure_can_we_be_that_the_bending_of_light_grazing_the_Sun_as_well_as_the_Shapiro_delay_is_free_of_any_refractional_bending

Principally see the responses by Dishman, and his references.

I've seen similar questions and arguments in other sites, all non-mainstream, and not published articles in any mainstream journal. You might be paying too much attention to 'alternative science'.